# Spring cloud performance tunning

Tags: spring-cloud

I'm doing a performance test against a Spring Cloud application. When number of concurrent users exceeds 150, it starts to give "Forwarding error"

```
{"timestamp":1458685370986,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException","message":"Forwarding error"}
```

Which parameter I should adjust to get rid of the error?

Comment: How about a little more information? What parts of spring cloud are you using (dependencies)? What versions? What is your configuration?

Comment: I'm using Eureka, Zuul and Spring Boot app. The request goes to the Zuul server and forwards the request to the app.

Comment: I had a similar problem when i was using ANGEL I switched to BRIXTON that somehow seem to resolve the issue.. You can try that if you are using ANGEL.

Answer (score 1):

You should post your logs for the error, without that we can only guess what the exact error is. As `Forwarding error` reported by `ZuulExcetption` is a generic error.

See this link for the [RibbonRoutingFilter.forward()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/route/RibbonRoutingFilter.java#RibbonRoutingFilter.forward%28com.netflix.niws.client.http.RestClient%2Cjava.lang.String%2Ccom.netflix.client.http.HttpRequest.Verb%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Boolean%2Corg.springframework.util.MultiValueMap%2Corg.springframework.util.MultiValueMap%2Cjava.io.InputStream%29) method which actually reports this error. I'm adding the code here for the backup.

```java
private HttpResponse forward(RestClient restClient, String service, Verb verb, String uri, Boolean retryable,
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, MultiValueMap<String, String> params,
        InputStream requestEntity) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> info = this.helper.debug(verb.verb(), uri, headers, params,
            requestEntity);
    RibbonCommand command = new RibbonCommand(service, restClient, verb, uri, retryable,
            headers, params, requestEntity);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = command.execute();
        this.helper.appendDebug(info, response.getStatus(),
                revertHeaders(response.getHeaders()));
        return response;
    }
    catch (HystrixRuntimeException ex) {
        info.put("status", "500");
        if (ex.getFallbackException() != null
                && ex.getFallbackException().getCause() != null
                && ex.getFallbackException().getCause() instanceof ClientException) {
            ClientException cause = (ClientException) ex.getFallbackException()
                    .getCause();
            throw new ZuulException(cause, "Forwarding error", 500, cause
                    .getErrorType().toString());
        }
        throw new ZuulException(ex, "Forwarding error", 500, ex.getFailureType()
                .toString());
    }

}
```

As you can see that only viable place where the error can be generated is in `command.execute()`, where command is an instance of `HystrixCommand`. Here is a link for the [execute() method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.netflix.hystrix/hystrix-core/1.4.4/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.java#HystrixCommand.execute%28%29) in `HystrixCommand`.

Below is the code for backup.

```java
public R execute() {
    try {
        return queue().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw decomposeException(e);
    }
}
```

Here the `queue()` is a [Future instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

Most common error that can occur with the Future is a timeout exception. Since here `Future` instance `queue()` is not bound by any timetout value, it can go on waiting for ever.

However most of the time API which make use of `Future` have a thread monitoring the time they take and they interrupt it after a certain period of time. Same is done by `Ribbon`.

If yours indeed is a timeout issue then an easy solution is to increase [Ribbon timeout value](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Programmers-Guide) by using following property.

```
ribbon.ReadTimeout=10000
//or
<client-name>.ribbon.ReadTimeout=10000
```

Time out majorly can occur if the tomcat server which hosts the service which is proxied by the Zuul has too much load. It's whole thread pool is exhausted thus resulting in the next requests having to wait for long time.

This can probably be alleviated by change the number of threads that your service tomcat has by using following property.

```
server.tomcat.max-threads=0
```

By default it's set to 0, which leaves it to the embedded server's default. In tomcat's case it's 200. See the reference [maxThreads property in tomcat.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html)

Note: To increase the thread pool size we have to make sure that the machine has that capacity to provide resources if that many threads were to be in execution simultaneously.